# Cannot run C program with MinGW

Tags: c, windows, compilation, runtime, mingw32

I am having issues running a basic helloworld program in C with MinGW on Windows 8.1-64. Each time I try to run the executable, nothing happens. I see no printed output, I am unable to continue using the shell, until I Ctrl-C. There is no error message that gets generated when I compile or run.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

printf("Hello World");
return 0;

}
```

I compile and execute the generated a.exe file with

```
gcc main.c
./a.exe
```

I running the program using the MinGW shell.

I have tried using Cygwin, and Visual Studio to run the same C program, but the same issue occurs and I need to use Task Manager to end task.

Do you have any potiential solutions that would allow me to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a CR, \n, to your string.

Comment: It still behaves similarly, where I see no output, and I am unable to type new commands to the command prompt unless I Ctrl-C.

Comment: gcc main.c  will not generate a.exe , please delete the a.exe you see, and recompile to be sure you are doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: I have deleted the existing a.exe file, and I can confirm running "gcc main.c" creates an "a.exe" file in the directory.

Comment: I have same probleme, have you find issue ?? No errors when I compile my program .exe is create but when I want start exe I have no response @TrueArTs

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, for other folks who stumble across this I wasn't able to fix this issue. Eventually I ended up upgrading my laptop to Windows 10 and was able to resolve this issue, obviously something else there had solved my issue.